# Auto slide in both direction in ViewPager in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

*I am trying to auto slide image in both direction but, I am unable to de so. It is only auto sliding from left to right. *

> This is the code for MainActivity where i created my viewPager

```
**ViewPager viewPager; 
  viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
  Timer timer;
  **  
final long DELAY_MS = 1000;//delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed
    final long PERIOD_MS = 5000; // time in milliseconds between successive task executions.
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    public void setUpOffers(){
        ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<String> promoCodes = new ArrayList<>();
        for(OfferDetail offerDetail:new utility().getSpOffers()){
            urls.add(offerDetail.getImage());
            promoCodes.add(offerDetail.getPromo_code());
        }

        FeaturedOffersAdapter featuredOffersAdapter = new FeaturedOffersAdapter(MainActivity.this,urls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(featuredOffersAdapter);

        //viewPager.setScrollDurationFactor(10);

        /*After setting the adapter use the timer */
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = () -> {
            if (currentPage == urls.size()) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        };

        timer = new Timer(); // This will create a new Thread
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // task to be scheduled
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, DELAY_MS, PERIOD_MS);
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell whether you want it for first time or for entire tabs on viewpager

Comment: I want it for entire tab. LtR then RtL continously.